# AnyLogic RackStore - Delaying the storage with a Probability Distribution

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to model a storage (using "RackStore") where the pallets will be stored in the "Pallet Rack" for a certain period. The models trigger a pallet of 12 (source) each time.

1. I tried using the delay in the "RackStore" but the delay is for each agent (per pallet) rather than having all the pallets per source (12 pallets).
2. I tried using "Delay" block but the delay is also for each agent(per pallet) rather than having all the pallets per source (12 pallets).

I hope that someone will be able to advise me on how to create the delay for the entire pallets per source and not each individual agent (per pallet).

Thank in advance.

#anylogic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Batch/Unbatch functionality in AnyLogic:

[image]

There have been various cases where I used pickup-dropoff combination, but I think batch/unbatch is sufficient for your case.

Put 12 in the batch size. After the process is done, unbatch them.

[image]

Comment: What if, moving forward if the source (pallets) is varied? For example, I use the probability distribution for the input of the pallets.

Comment: create a variable called `batchSize`, update it whenever you want. Instead of typing 12 into the batch size, type the variable name `batchSize`.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information. Would you mind making a snapshot of the variable batchSize?

Comment: Just drag and drop variable from the palette, call it `batchSize` and set the type to `Double`. That's it. Please don't forget to upvote and/or accept as answer so that others can also benefit.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a go and see how it is. Since this is my first posting, how do you upvote or accept as answer?

Comment: well noted. I'll do that. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, can the variable be adjusted automatically based on the source? for example, if the source produces 5 pallets, can the variable batchSize automatically change to 5?

Comment: yes, everything is possible in AnyLogic:)

Comment: How to do that? Doing it automatically based on the source?

Comment: It depends on how you have built the model. If that 5 is static, inside source, you can write batchSize and regulate the value from there. If not- it changes every time, you need to create a separate variable to keep track of this. Once the batch is created, set it to zero for the next batch.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply. After I had put in the batch and unbatch block, during the run, an error occurred saying "the agent not in network". Not sure whats happening.